# Converting Ubuntu to UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Does anyone know of an Easy solution to dual boot Window and Ubuntu with UEFI after you have already installed Ubuntu or for that matter from the get-go? I have tried enabling CSM in my BIOS and using it for Windows but Windows runs really slow cause I guess it requires UEFI for 64 bit applications. All the posts and tutorials on this are real confusing so if you can't make this for a laymen to understand, I guess Windows has just won this battle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair) or [How to change ubuntu install from legacy to uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi)

Comment: The Second link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi) looks as if it may hold the answer, When I get time I will try this, but it seems I have tried something along these lines before and the computer never boots to the live CD with EFI mode. I will follow the instructions closely and report back...Thanks!

Comment: Second Link works, 1st link is just utterly overwhelming for any Novice computer user, Please redirect all these type of questions to the appropriate answer. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi)