# can't boot into ubuntu after using boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I am absolutely new in ubuntu platform and i have little knowledge in ubuntu. My laptop is dell inspiron 3467 and i dual boot ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10, here the thing is that my windows in uefi mode and i mistakenly installed ubuntu in legacy mode. So after installing ubuntu i restart pc and pc goes right through the windows so i run boot-repair in live usb and follow everything but it says there is an error and show that sda10(in which i install ubuntu) have no grub. so i unplug it and try to boot ubuntu in legacy boot from internal hard drive, but it is going to grub rescue mode. So now i have ubuntu install in my pc i can't boot into it so how can i re-install grub to boot ubuntu, pls help me out guys.

Comment: Have a look at Pilot6's answer there https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi

Comment: Do not use Boot-Repair's auto fix, but use advanced mode and totally uninstall & reinstall grub boot loader. Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode and then add Boot-Repair from ppa. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & advanced screens: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/