# Installed Ubuntu in UEFI, but it runs on BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I specifically booted Ubuntu [17.10 amd64] live-usb in uefi, created partitions as shown on this image and installed it.: [image]

Later I checked if Ubuntu is running in UEFI and it's not.
I need to install Windows in dual-boot with the Ubuntu I already have installed, and I don't know how to go about this.

1. Should I delete the /boot/efi partition, then install Windows in Legacy? or,
2. Should I leave it as is, and install Windows in UEFI? or,
3. Should I leave it as is, and install Windows in Legacy? or,
4. (other option)

Also I'd love to know if I need to setup bootloaders like GRUB for this since I did a clean install of Ubuntu and I'm only installing Windows now. 
Thank you.

Comment: How it boots is how it installs. Knowing that Windows, unlike Ubuntu, strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode and MBR ("msdos") for Legacy, I would start by assuring the drive is in fact GPT, then disable any Legacy mode at UEFI settings just in case and start over. Doing so Ubuntu will definitely be installed in UEFI mode and Windows can be added later without too much trouble. No special actions regarding bootloaders are required, you just need to know how UEFI works and no, a separate `/boot` partition isn't required.

Comment: What would you suggest doing if reinstalling Ubuntu weren't an option?

Comment: If the partition table is incorrect you won't be able to install Windows in the recommended mode (UEFI) so, that being the case, there's no solution. If GPT and still Ubuntu was installed in Legacy (so weird that I wager it's impossible, you must have made some mistake) then there are methods to make it an UEFI install but I don't know how, perhaps this https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi

Comment: if you do want to keep a separate /boot partition, 500MB is too small unless you are frugal about cleaning up old kernels.Even then I'd go with 1GB. Also 120GB is a little excessive for /, 20-50GB is plenty.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. 
I'll check that link out @MichaelBay and let you know if I get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MichaelBay for providing this link:

[How to change ubuntu install from legacy to uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi)

The answer there by Rod Smith solved the issue. 
Ubuntu is now UEFI and now I can proceed to installing Windows.