# Dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows issue?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader, acer

I tried to dual boot my windows 10 Acer aspire laptop 8gb ram and 256ssd with ubuntu, I successfully did it but, I have ubuntu on legacy mode and windows 10 on UEFI mode so every time I want to switch I have to open bios and change boot mode in between legacy and UEFI. I was trying to get the gnu option to choose between two OS, I tried various options through ubuntu boot-repair but no luck. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: With UEFI Acer has an unique requirement of setting "trust" from within UEFI on ubuntu entry, which may be unknown until you set trust & rename it. You may need to update UEFI and if SSD, update SSD firmware. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the best solution would be to clean reinstall Ubuntu ...
but there are still a couple of solutions that are worth trying

see this post : [How to change ubuntu install from legacy to uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi)

I have tried & method 1 did work for me on a HP laptop, Win10 1903 + Ubuntu 18.04

> Method 1: Disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy mode" or "BIOS mode" support) in your firmware. Boot the Ubuntu
>   installer in its "try before installing" mode. Double-check that
>   you've booted in EFI mode by looking for a directory called
>   /sys/firmware/efi. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode and can
>   continue; but if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode and should
>   review your firmware settings and how you created the boot medium.
>   Download and run the Boot Repair program, as described here. Tell Boot
>   Repair to repair your installation. Reboot. With any luck, GRUB will
>   appear and give you the option of booting either Windows or Ubuntu. In
>   some rare cases, the system may boot straight to Ubuntu in EFI mode
>   and you'll need to tweak GRUB to get Windows to appear in the GRUB
>   menu.

PS : rule #1 make a backup, rule #2 make a f*** backup, rule #3 ... check your backup is up-to-date and valid ;)

Nath