# How can I upgrade from BIOS to UEFI in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, uefi, mbr, nvme

As per subject, would like to upgrade my *20.04* install from BIOS to UEFI.
I have to do this to leverage re-[BAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration) to then have a quicker/better communication between my videocard and RAM.

I read that I should have to:

1. Convert my main disk from MBR -> GPT (would I still be able to boot in BIOS mode after this? Should I simply use [gdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html)?)
2. Resize my current `/` partition from 128 GiB to 127 and leave 1 GiB at the beginning for a FAT32/EFI
3. Mark to first partition to be EFI (Is it the case? How should I do this?)
4. Install the new (`.efi`) boot loader on there, pointing to my *EXT4* `/` partition (How can I do this?)
5. Ask the motherboard to use EFI instead of BIOS

Am I correct in my understanding? How con I implement points 3 and 4?

I did not mention backups etc etc, but I got a 2 TiB external SSD (should be a fast USB) and I plan to `dd if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=/<my temp mount>/backup.img` (to do a backup of my 1 TiB main nvme disk - when unmounted of course).

Another strategy would be to convert from MBR -> GPT (still in BIOS mode if possible) and then perform a *fresh* Ubuntu reinstall preserving `/home` partition on `nvme1n1`.
But then I would need to have both my user ids preserved (I have other 4 drives with proper permissions setup and wouldn't want to `chown` all the way around my filesystem).

What's your recommendation?

Thanks!

Ps. I will upgrade to 22.04 as soon as it will be deemed *safe*.

Comment: I do not like dd for backups. And you cannot easily restore MBR install to gpt. You can use gpt to boot in BIOS mode, but gpt needs a tiny 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. If you convert, at minimum you need to reinstall grub & update all UUIDs in fstab. You should also export list of installed apps & rsync data on boot drive. And any server apps in / and perhap some settings in /etc. I suggest new clean install & restore from backup, but it may depend on how you backed up data & configuration of drive. Be sure to create users in same order as actually 1000, 1001, 1002, etc

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi

Comment: @Rinzwind looks like a duplicate to me. :)

Comment: What does mode (UEFI vs. legacy) or disk partitioning (GPT vs. MSDOS) have to do with PCI bus enumeration?

Comment: @ubfan1 It's about resizeable BAR

Comment: No, it's not. It's about reading something complex which is targeted to engineers only and misunderstanding it completely.

Comment: I have just finished updating my wife's Ubuntu disk similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403792/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. But with internal disks. The method will boot either BIOS or UEFI. I reused boot, /home and NTFS data partitions from her previous disk and overwrote Ubuntu 18.04 with 22.04. Previously the disk was formatted MSDOS, now it is GPT and I can now boot Windows from GRUB.

Comment: Boot-Repair will not create an ESP, so you must have the EFI system partition before running boot repair.

Comment: @ChanganAuto https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/news/geforce-rtx-30-series-resizable-bar-support/